# emacs key binding

Tags: emacs, clojure, key

I'm new to emacs so I need simple tip. I'd like to use Command-RET to eval last expression - to do this:

clojure-mode.el:

```
(define-key map "\C-x\C-e" 'lisp-eval-last-sexp)
```

And I don't want to change original clojure-mode.el file. How can I define key binding that will execute C-x\C-e and that will call 'lisp-eval-last-sexp? It would be great solution for me, because I can't bind Command-RET directly with:

```
local-set-key
```

to 'lisp-eval-last-sexp, emacs can't find this function.

thanks in advance,
Bartek

**Update:**

finally it turned out that I needed to write:

```
M-x
describe-key
^X ^E
```

and it returned me:

```
^X ^E runs the command slime-eval-last-expression, which is an
interactive Lisp function in `slime.el'.

It is bound to ^X ^E, <menu-bar> <SLIME> <Evaluation> <Eval Last
Expression>, <A-return>.

(slime-eval-last-expression)

Evaluate the expression preceding point.

[back]
```

and then I bound my keys to function

```
'slime-eval-last-expression
```

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ir should be `eval-last-sexp` not `lisp-eval-last-sexp`?

Comment: nope, It's not working the same way

Comment: See answer below.  Try eval-print-last-sexp, that is what C-j is bound to in my emacs.

Answer (score 2):

You can rebind keys in your .emacs file you don't need to change clojure-mode.el,

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
                '(lambda ()
                   (define-key clojure-mode-map 
                     "\e\C-x" 'lisp-eval-defun)))
```

Comment: Are you missing `\C-` in your `define-key`?

Comment: Strange but good to know. Might wanna fix it anyway so this is clearer. Dunno what magick is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to set it to eval-print-last-sexp instead.  That is what C-j is bound to.